# RS 485 communications not working, A, B both low

Tags: serial, rs485

My question is: for RS485, does A or B (one of the two) have to be HIGH by default? If there are only 2 communication nodes in the network, should one of the nodes pull A or B (one of the two) HIGH by default?

Here is my situation. I'm looking for debugging suggestions.

I want to have an industrial computer (IPC) to communicate to a [LT1785](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1785-1785A-1791-1791A.pdf) chip over RS 485. Only 3 wires are used:

- A
- B
- Ground

It does **not** work. LT1785 receives the wrong bytes, but is repeatable. Here are the experiments we have done:

- use this [USB to 485 converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B416CPK) to compare vs. RS485 (DB9) port on IPC
- use oscilloscope to read A, B signal from 485 port (IPC) vs. USB converter. The signals look different. USB converter has one signal high by default. 485 port has both signals low by default.
- 485 (IPC) to 485 (IPC): minicom WORKS (two ports can communicate w/ each other)
- usb (IPC) to 485 (IPC): minicom WORKS (two ports can communicate w/ each other)
- usb (IPC) to LT1785: WORKS (two ports can communicate w/ each other)
- 485 (IPC) to LT1785: DOES NOT WORK (wrong bytes received, but repeatable)

Here are the oscilloscope readings for 485 port vs. USB converter.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just swap A and B over on one device. It won't hurt.

Comment: Agreed. A is non-INV input, but your driver to this may be inverted

Comment: Typical RS485 line drivers will only pull A or B high or low *when they're enabled*. When the line driver is disabled, A & B will float unless you have a biasing network connected at some point on the bus to pull the floating lines to a known default state. It's possible that your off-the-shelf USB converter and/or RS485 port in your IPC has a biasing network already. A "raw" LT1785 does not. Typically the line driver is only enabled while it's transmitting data.

Comment: The convention, and even the names, for A and B and which is inverted and which is non-inverted are all over the place. The standard says one thing but a lot of devices use the opposite. Always best to check the graphs on the datasheet for the driver to see the relationship for each pin on the differential side relative to the single-ended side. https://www.bb-elec.com/Learning-Center/All-White-Papers/Serial/%E2%80%A2-Polarities-for-Differential-Pair-Signals-(RS-422.aspx

Comment: The 'scope shows the exact same data - the only difference is the 485 port idles to 0v, while the USB port does not idle. This should not matter. I think the LT1785 is reading the right data. How are you interpreting it? Don't be surprised if 8 data bits, Even parity, and 1 stop bit are used - the protocol parameters for 485 are all over the place.

Comment: @rdtsc here is our protocol: parity none, stop bits 1, byte size 8, baud rate 115200.